# Slicing a list of tuples within a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I'm creating a program that analyzes the stock market. So far I'm only using Python's default data structures (let me know if pandas would let me accomplish this easier - or if at all possible)

I have a dictionary of stocks. The key of the stock is associated with a list of tuples that contain daily statistics about the stock for the past year.

For example, calling `data['AAPL']` will return a list of 252 tuples, each tuple containing that day's trading statistics for Apple. Calling `data['AAPL'][0]` will return the tuple on the first day of trading last year for Apple. And I can call `data['AAPL'][0][1]`, which is the stock price of the first day of trading last year for Apple.

Now I'm running into trouble with slicing this thing. I want to grab only the stock price for the first five days of trading. What I thought would work - `data['AAPL'][0:4][1]` - doesn't work; it returns the whole second day of trading instead of stock price for the first five days. Can I slice a list of tuples within a dictionary like this? Or how do I go about it?

I'm still relatively new to Python, so any and all help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can achieve the result with `[data['APPL'][x][1] for x in xrange(4)]` (*note*: `xrange` in Python 2.x and `range` in Python 3.x). I'll let you research how that works...

Comment: ^^ - read about "list comprehensions"

Comment: Thanks a bunch, worked perfectly. Still have plenty to learn about Python.